# Compile Time DEFINEs in an ASP.NET Web Deployment Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, trace, web-deployment-project

My environment is Visual Studio 2005. My specific problem is that I want to define `TRACE`.

I have a Web Site Project that send trace messages when run out of the ASP.NET Development Server thanks to defining it in the `system.codedom` element of the web.config.

When I deploy to IIS, I do so via a web deployment project. So the site is precompiled. Naturally, these entries serve no purpose on a compiled website.

My question is how do I define `TRACE` in the web deployment project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual Studio IDE does not allow you to set compile time constants in web deployment projects as far as I can tell. However, since a .wdproj file is just an msbuild file, you can edit it with a text editor. You need to add a  element to the  sections as illustrated in the screen shot in the provided link.

I cannot change the link to an image since new users apparently can't add images:
[Annotated screenshot of .wdproj in a text editor http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/1719/deploymentproject.png](http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/1719/deploymentproject.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to #defines in C#.  That said, it sounds like you want to use conditional tracing, which is easily accomplished.  If you have diagnostic code throughout your project but want to define it, use the built in trace functionality, for example

System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Some debug output");

Then, in your webconfig, you can configure it on/off using

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y89ed7z(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: Serapth,

Thanks for your reply. I think I was unclear in my question though. I understand I can turn on ASP.NET tracing in the web.config and get  the information showin in that link. However, what I want is for Trace.Trace(Information|Warning|Error)(message) to get sent to the trace listeners. That required TRACE to be defined. Also, #define works just fine in C#. Give it a try.